# Summation of Legendre polynomial series

Tags: legendre-polynomials

How do I find the sum $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n P_n(x)$$ where $P_n$ are the $n$th order Legendre polynomials? I tried using the generating function but I was not able to arrive at an answer. Any hints appreciated.

Comment: You only need to evaluate the generating function at $t=-1$.

Comment: @conditionalMethod Its not allowed to substitute the value of $t$ in the generating function

Comment: I don't know who will stop me. Oops, I just did it. Wait, I will even dare to write $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nP_n(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2+2x}}$. Send the cops.

Comment: @conditionalMethod The generating function is derived by assuming $t$ is very small. The cops are on their way!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem in using the generating function.
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2-2rx+1}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P_n(x)r^n$$
holds for all $|r|<1$ (as the radius of convergence in the complex plane is the distance to the first singular point, which here lie both on the unit circle) and $|x| \le 1$ and it holds also for $r=-1$, your example.
Thus
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P_n(x)(-1)^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2+2x}}$$
As already remarked by ${conditionalMethod}$. Note that this leads to an ambigious result for $x=-1$.